# Why does "Azure Web Services" show up as third party code in Lighthouse report?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, lighthouse

I have a Vue app hosted as an Azure App Service, and am analyzing it with Lighthouse in Chrome. Under the "Reduce the impact of third-party code" diagnostic it shows "Azure Web Services" as blocking third party code.

Is there actually something that Azure is loading, or is this Lighthouse classifying my application as third party code because it happens to run on Azure?

[[image: lighthouse report[1]]